# How to solve conflicting members in scala trait (org.slf4j.Logger/com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger)

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, conflicting-libraries

I'm using Spark 2.1.1 . This is my problem:

I have 2 files in the same directory named **tools**. One is **main_process.scala** and the other one is **main_process_fun.scala**. The files, basically looks like this:

**1.- main_process.scala:**

```
package mod.pack.tools

import x.y.spark.InitSpark
import com.typesafe.config.Config

trait main_process extends InitSpark with main_process_fun {
  this: InitSpark  =>
  /**
    * @param spark  Initialized SparkSession
    * @param config Config retrieved from args
    */
  override def run(spark: SparkSession, config: Config): Int = {
    logger.info("LOG")
    implicit val sparkSes = spark

    pre_defined_f1(config).flatMap(cfg => pre_defined_f2(cfg).flatMap(pre_defined_f3(_, cfg))) match {
      case Success(_) =>
        logger.info("OK")
      case Failure(e) =>
        logger.info("ERROR")
    }
  }
}
```

**2.- main_process_fun.scala:**

```
package mod.pack.tools

import mod.pack.tools.another_folder.another_trait
import com.typesafe.config.Config

trait main_process_fun extends another_trait with com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging {

  def pre_defined_f1(conf: Config): Try[Config] = Try {
    blablabla
  }

  def pre_defined_f2(conf: Config)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Try[DataFrame] = Try {
    blablabla
    logger.info("LOG")
  }

  def pre_defined_f3(conf: Config): Column = {
    blablabla
    logger.info("LOG")
  }
}
```

I have an error when trying to compile the project. The error says:

```
trait main_process inherits conflicting members
lazy value logger in trait LazyLogging of type org.slf4j.Logger and
lazy value logger in trait LazyLogging of type com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
(Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in trait main_process.)
trait main_process extends InitSpark with main_process_fun {
```

I've already tried to override the logger, but I got this error message:

```
lazy value logger has incompatible type
```

I also tried to import main_process_fun instead of extending it from main_process, but without success, I don't know if I did it the wrong way or if the idea itself is bad to solve this issue.

I would greatly appreciate your help to solve this inheritance conflict!

By the way, logger is defined as:

```
package com.typesafe.scalalogging
trait LazyLogging extends scala.AnyRef {
 @scala.transient
 protected lazy val logger : com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages explain that there are two versions of `logger`, one in `org.slf4j.Logger` and the other in `com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger`. These conflict with each other, so you need to drop one. `InitSpark` appears to use the first of these, so use the same type in the second trait as well:

```
trait main_process_fun extends another_trait with org.slf4j.Logger {
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution with the help of Tim!

First:

```
trait main_process_fun extends another_trait {
```

Then I imported:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

And finally, in every method that use logger value, I declared:

```
val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[main_process_fun])
```

Thank you!